# prepared statements Mysqli не работает запрос

Tags: php, mysqli, запрос, preparedstatement

Что то типа такого и не работает код  , почему ?

```
<?php 
$db->set_charset('utf8');
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) 
{
    $name = $db->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $email = $db->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
    $comment = $db->real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']));

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
    $currentTime = time();
    $dateTime = strftime('%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S', $currentTime);
    $dateTime;
    $post_id = $_GET['id'];
    if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($comment)) 
    {
        $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "Заполните все поля";
            Redirect_to("fullpost/{$post_id}");
        exit;
    }

    if (strlen($comment)>500) 
    {
        $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "only 500 characters allowed in Comment";
        Redirect_to("fullpost/{$post_id}");

    }
    else 
    {
        global $db;



        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO comments (datetime, name,email,comment,approvedby,status,admin_panel_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssi',$dateTime, $name, $email, $comment,'pending', 'ON',$post_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->affected_rows === 1)
        {
        $_SESSION['SuccessMessage'] = "Комментарий  отправлен";
        Redirect_to("fullpost/{$post_id}");
        }
        if ($stmt->affected_rows === 0)
        {
        $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "fail.";
        Redirect_to("fullpost/{$post_id}");
        }
        if ($stmt->affected_rows === -1)
        {
        $_SESSION['ErrorMessage'] = "fail.";
        Redirect_to("fullpost/{$post_id}");
        }

    }


}
 ?>



<form action="/fullpost.php?id=<?php echo $post_id ?>  " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>

Email: <input type="email" name="email"><br>

Comment:<br>
<textarea name="comment" ></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitted">
```

И короче оно отправляет форму эту и я оказываюсь на fullpost.php?id=111 и пустой экран(белый) а должно на fullpost/111 и отправится комментарий

Comment: Перед тем как я решил сменить код какой то черт всунуть эксплойт в мои поля формы короче получилось там яваскрипт и удалял body(и это куки были) .ну я все почистил добавил htmlspecialchars ; но хочу сделать prepared statements ; и может это из за этого что тег body удалялся я получаю пустую страницу ( хотя я удалил куки ).

Comment: Добавил весь код который обрабатывает форму и форму( чтобы легче было может быть)

Answer (score 0):

> Что то типа такого и не работает код , почему ?

`$post_id = $_GET['id'];` - это строка, а в `bind_param('ssssssi'` указано, что это `integer`.

Надо поменять на:

```
$post_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

или

```
$post_id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

---

P.S.: Про микс **$_POST** и **$_GET** для передачи `post_id` лучше использовать скрытые поля:

aka

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" id="..." name="id"/>
```

и тогда на стороне "сервера":

```
$post_id = intval($_POST['id']);
```